# Find absent values in a junction table, rectify SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables I'm dealing with, `patientTbl` which consists of a PK called patientID and a junction table called `icdJxn`.  The query below is set up to find the values of `patientID` present in `patientTbl` NOT present in `icdjxn`.

```
select patienttbl.patientid, icdjxn.patientID as [nulls?]
from patientTbl left outer join icdjxn on patientTbl.patientID = icdjxn.patientID
where (icdjxn.patientID is null)
```

I'm pretty sure that gives me the values from `patientTbl.patientID` that are not present in `icdjxn.patientID`.  Is there a way to `insert into` this query so I won't run into any PK/FK issues?

Comment: You want to insert into the `jxn` table any missing values?

Comment: If it's a junction table, aren't you going to need another value to insert?

Comment: Correct.  this is a big mock database to show some people the basics of how they work.  I tried to just do a cross join but the other table in this many-to-many relationship had too many rows and the query returned resulted in an overflow error.

Comment: @RedFilter normally, yes :). This is just a demonstration of some basic database stuff.  I planned on filling in the other side with something like set code='blah' where code is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A merge would do the job if you are on SQL Server 2008 or later.

```
merge icdjxn as S
using patientTbl as T
on S.patientID = T.patientID
when not matched then
  insert (patientID) values (patientID);
```

Comment: I'd love to mark this as a correct answer, but you misspelled a word :)

Comment: i was being facetious i hope you could tell.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie It proves that I did not test my answer. I usually do that but not this time. Don't know what facetious means just yet but I will find out :).

Comment: No I know and I could tell :).

Comment: if i can teach someone a new word every day then i've done a good thing. tack!